# NextJS - Production Hot Reloading

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Are there any examples out there of injecting new ReactJS components at Runtime, e.g:

1. A build is deployed on production is stable and running.
2. We need to add a component or a new route without running through an entire deploy process.
3. An additional usecase : the application ships with all the components ( e.g: A CMS Module library) - Only certain components were enabled in layout at build time but need more to be added later via a config.

Approaches I have considered.

1. Using `next` `getStaticPaths` and then using a override in the front-end to inject client side components. This will most probably be *seen* at runtim
2. Use a more faster deploy system - This is more obvious but imagine lots of changes within a day and multiple deploys.

Any similar problems or approaches people would have tried would be great.

### Update Nov 2022

If you are searching on the internet and this comes up, Zack Jackson's Module Federation supposedly achieves this and is called live code sharing via Module federation - https://module-federation.github.io/ There is a NextJS *Paid* plugin https://app.privjs.com/buy/packageDetail?pkg=@module-federation/nextjs-mf (supports only CSR currently)

Comment: whats your problem with lots of changes within a day? you can easily deploy without without letting go down the app...

Comment: Works for a single small scale app but for large deployments e.g: a store, it can be a challenge.

Additional example: We wanted to change our maps provider but not do a huge deploy for this.

Comment: hi @Ramakay, like this we want users to enjoy new features without any hard refresh after a fresh build , did u have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would lose out on a lot of built-in build optimizations from Next by trying to circumvent the standard build process, e.g. automatic code-splitting [as described here](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-2#improved-code-splitting-strategy).

However, you might find the `fallback` feature solves your problem entirely - the `fallback` feature was meant for large ecommerce sites like it sounds like you're working with. As stated at [the fallback true docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#when-is-fallback-true-useful):

> useful if your app has a very large number of static pages that depend on data (think: a very large e-commerce site). You want to pre-render all product pages, but then your builds would take forever.